# Replace an SVG <g> tag using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to replace an SVG  tag using Nokogiri but I can't seem to find a method to replace the tag.

My attempt:

```
xml = Nokogiri.parse sample.svg
xml.search("//xmlns:g[@id='Placements']")
```

Though it finds the  tag with id `Placements` but what is the method to replace the tag with another tag?

I tried:

```
xml = Nokogiri.parse sample.svg
xml.search("//xmlns:g[@id='Placements']").replace '<g id=example></g>'
```

It return an error:

```
undefined method `replace' for #<Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet:0x00007f4e458bbb78>
```

How do I replace a  tag in SVG using Nokogiri?

Comment: What exactly is unclear to you [in the tutorial](https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/modifying_an_html_xml_document.html)? Why would you expect `NodeSet#replace` method to exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet

Gives you a list of all the actions you can take upon that nodeset. The question is do you want to completely change everything within it? That would include all nodes nested inside it. Just checking you are only getting one result because search allows for multiple nodes to be found and put into a nodeset to be looked at.

If you are certain you are where you would like to be and want to completely change / remove the nodeset you would

```
xml.search("//xmlns:g[@id='Placements']").before('<g id=example></g>')
```

Then remove the set you have selected:

```
xml.search("//xmlns:g[@id='Placements']").delete
```

What bothers me here is it is giving you a nodeset which implies you have more than one tag. Try doing:

```
xml.search("//xmlns:g[@id='Placements']").length
```

To make sure you have the singular tag you want. Doing:

```
i = 0
xml.search("//xmlns:g[@id='Placements']").each do |node|
  puts node
  puts i
  i += 1
end
```

Can give you a better idea of which particular node you want. Then with the help of the index of the specific node you want you can simply select it with:

```
xml.search("//xmlns:g[@id='Placements']")[i]
```

Changing the i out for what the specific index position was.
The problem that I see is that you are still not on your singular node that you want to change since it is claiming to return a nodeset to you.

Once you find your singular node that replace should work:
https://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change one id to another - just assign it.

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.read("sample.svg"))
doc.css('g#Placements')[0]["id"] = "example"

File.write("new.svg", doc.to_xml)
```